# Is possible to animate $('html,body') except one element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I'd like to know if there's some way to get:

```
$('html,body').animate({scrollTop: "+=1800px"},2000);
```

but with some element with other values to the animate function.

Comment: Instead of animating `<html>` and `<body>` tags, why not use `<div>`s in the body?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "other values"? Do you want to use another element's metrics to compute the animation values?

Comment: Also, [`position: fixed`](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/position.html) on the "static" element may be what you're looking for.

Comment: Jared: Using the divs is an option for sure but I didn't know if there was some other way.   minitech: other values I mean other speed to top for example.

Comment: There is a bug in Opera (at least older versions) which will animate BOTH the `html` and `body` tag separately. Please refer to [this post](http://www.zachstronaut.com/posts/2009/01/18/jquery-smooth-scroll-bugs.html) for a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Possibility 1

No, as every other element is *inside* the body, it will animate with it.
You could, however, include everything appart from the thing you don't want to be animated in one big div with maximum with and height, and alter the code to just animate that div.

### Possibility 2

I just thought of something else. Not sure if it'll work though.
Use this as a selector for the animation: `$('body *').not('dontAnimateThese')`.
Replace `dontAnimateThese` by the elements wich shouldn't be animated.

Comment: Thanks Robin for the explanation. I tried your second possibility but i couldn't get it to work. I tried   $('body *').not('#divid').animate({scrollTop: "+=1800px"},2000); It was right this that you were saying?

Comment: Yeah, but as I said, I wasn't sure if the second method would work.

Comment: The way I tried didn't work but thanks anyway. The first part of the answer is what i was looking for.